# PyQt5 stop timer inside a widget that was added from a different class

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget, qmainwindow, qtimer

I would like to display the current date and time on the top of multiple windows, so I created a class of this top widget. It works, however when I switch to another window, the timer keeps running on the previous window too. How can I stop the timer right before switching window, perhaps keep the same instance running on the new window?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys
from datetime import datetime

CurrentWindow = None

class TopBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.labelTime = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.labelTime.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: white")

        background = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        background.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.6)")
        background.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 30)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(background)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)
        hbox.addWidget(self.labelTime, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
        self.timer.start()

        self.displayTime()


    def displayTime(self):
        print(self.parent())
        self.labelTime.setText(datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))


class Window1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        widgetTop = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        widgetTop.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 30)

        layoutTop = QHBoxLayout(widgetTop)
        layoutTop.addWidget(TopBar())
        layoutTop.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText('Go to Window2')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.goToWindow2)

        layoutCenter = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layoutCenter.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.show()


    def goToWindow2(self):
        global CurrentWindow
        CurrentWindow = Window2()
        self.close()


class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        widgetTop = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        widgetTop.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 30)

        layoutTop = QHBoxLayout(widgetTop)
        layoutTop.addWidget(TopBar())
        layoutTop.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText('Go to Window1')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.goToWindow1)

        layoutCenter = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layoutCenter.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.show()


    def goToWindow1(self):
        global CurrentWindow
        CurrentWindow = Window1()
        self.close()



if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the QTimer execution slows down the application.

But I will still show you how to stop it from another window. To do this you must access the object so you must become a member of the class, and then when you change the window you stop it with the stop method of the QTimer.

```
class Window1(QMainWindow):
    # ...

    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        layoutTop = QHBoxLayout(widgetTop)
        self.topbar = TopBar()
        layoutTop.addWidget(self.topbar)
        layoutTop.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # ...

    def goToWindow2(self):
        global CurrentWindow
        self.topbar.timer.stop()
        CurrentWindow = Window2()
        self.close()


class Window2(QMainWindow):
    # ...

    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        layoutTop = QHBoxLayout(widgetTop)
        self.topbar = TopBar()
        layoutTop.addWidget(self.topbar)
        layoutTop.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # ...

    def goToWindow1(self):
        global CurrentWindow
        self.topbar.timer.stop()
        CurrentWindow = Window1()
        self.close()
```

If you still consider that the cause of the error is to have several QTimer then in the following code there will only be one TopBar and they will change the widget using a QStackedWidget

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys
from datetime import datetime


class TopBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
        self.labelTime = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelTime.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: white")

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.6)")
        self.setFixedHeight(30)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)
        hbox.addWidget(self.labelTime, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
        self.timer.start()

        self.displayTime()

    def displayTime(self):
        self.labelTime.setText(datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))


class Window(QWidget):
    changeWindow = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def changeTo(self, index):
        def callback():
            self.changeWindow.emit(index)

        return callback


class Window1(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setText("Go to Window2")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.changeTo(1))

        layoutCenter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layoutCenter.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


class Window2(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setText("Go to Window1")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.changeTo(0))

        layoutCenter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layoutCenter.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.topbar = TopBar()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.topbar)

        stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        lay.addWidget(stacked_widget)

        for w in (Window1(), Window2()):
            stacked_widget.addWidget(w)
            if isinstance(w, Window):
                w.changeWindow.connect(stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The second option seems to be the optimal solution for me, thank you for it! I had a time consuming function connected to the timer, which slowed down the application, but I replaced it with a QThread, which should also have only one instance with the second option.

Comment: @SmileXS4 So the problem was not the QTimer but the time-consuming function, don't you think that? In your question there is nothing about it. If you have a time-consuming task then you should not execute it in the main thread but in a secondary thread. If you want help you must provide a real [MRE] otherwise you will confuse the community.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question as I needed help to run only one timer at a time and not to run the application faster.